upload multiple images without overwriting existing images
I have a front end form for users to upload multiple images for an image gallery.  This works great, the issue I am having is that the when I upload new images the previously uploaded images are not being kept.  The images are being saved to a Solspace calendar even. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Here is my code
{% set possibleAssets = craft.assets()
  .volume('uploads')
  .relatedTo(event)
  .kind('image')
  .orderBy('filename ASC')
  .withTransforms([{ width: 100, height: 100 }])
  .all() %}

{# Get the currently related asset IDs #}
{% set relatedAssetIds = event is defined
  ? event.eventGalleryImages.ids()
  : [] %}

{# display the images #}
{% for possibleAsset in possibleAssets %}
  {{ possibleAsset.getImg({ width: 100, height: 100 }) }}
{% endfor %}

<br>

{# Provide each existing asset ID in the array of field data #}
{% for relatedAssetId in event.eventGalleryImages.ids() %}
  {{ input(
    'hidden',
    'eventGalleryImages[]',
    relatedAssetId
  ) }}
{% endfor %}

{{ input('file', 'eventGalleryImages[]', options={
  multiple: true,
}) }}

